# Teams - how to reduce the number of steps needed to login

Tags: microsoft-teams

Is there any way to reduce the obscene number of steps (currently 7 and rising) and data needed to login to Teams?
Currently, I need to:

- click to Get Started (A)
- insert my username (B)
- insert my password (B)
- wait for a call/sms (C)
- click Next to 'More information needed' window (D)
- click Skip on 'Keep your account secured' window (D)
- uncheck/leave alone the 'Allow my organization to manage my device' AND then click 'No, sign in to this app only' (D)

Remarks:

- (A) is useless: if I'm clicking the shortcut, it means I'm really interested to launch this app
- (B) could be store somewhere and not asked everytime
- (C) I personally hate this step
- (D) these were latter added, I'm not sure why

I disabled Teams to startup with windows, because I'm not using it everyday / it just simply slows me down when I'm starting my notebook for a quick check.

Thanks!
R
[image]

Comment: Those authentication process steps shouldn't be required every time. I would contact your DA and ask them to check the Teams settings in the admin console. New users at our company have to follow that process, but only once (unless the machine is re-imaged/they get a new machine).

Comment: thank you @spikey_richie. I'd already created a ticket and waiting for the IT department response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Micro$oft accustom us, the only way to reduce the number of login steps is to shutdown the PC with Teams working, so the next time you start your PC and you launch Teams, it will handle by itself all the necessary steps and you wouldn't have to do anything else but launch your Teams shortcut.

PS unfortunately, this is all I have (this is the answer from my it department) I have no documentation or citations 
R

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).